# svn repository url

Tags: svn, version-control, tortoisesvn

I have site stored in my wamp folder under www/sitename/ now i access this by typing

```
    http://localhost/sitename/
```

Now i want to have a repository of files in this folder.When i try to checkout in svn i have given **http://localhost/sitename/** in url repository.

But it is replying with error message redirects done

Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'http://localhost/sitename/'

**Question 1**:Will it really possible to form repository using url.If yes how this would happen in virtual host.

**Question 2**:How can i solve this error

Answer (score 3):

`http://localhost/sitename/` can't be both the website service *and* the SVN service.  It has to be one or the other.  When you access that URL (assuming port 80 for the http protocol) either the Apache process picks up the request and responds with the website *or* the SVN process picks up the request and responds with the repository.  Only one of them can listen for the request.

What you're trying to achieve isn't good practice anyway.  Your source control repository shouldn't also be the production application.  It should be separate.  So you'll want to create an SVN repository on something like `http://localhost/SVN` or any other non-production-application path.

While I *do* admire continuous deployment as a goal, skipping the deployment step altogether isn't how to achieve it :)  You should still separate the two different concerns (source control and production application) and deploy from source to production as a separate and discrete step.  Even if that step is simply a script that gets run automatically on checkin (hopefully after running any automated tests to validate the checkin before deployment).

Comment: I am using wamp and in you tube tutors they are not telling where they got the repository url could you please let me know how to get url repository

Comment: @user1093513: I'm afraid I can't really give step-by-step instructions for your system, I don't know how anything on your system is configured.  As a general word of advice, I wouldn't learn software development from YouTube :)  Essentially you need to configure your SVN service and create a repository there.  If that step was overlooked in some tutorial then you'll have to find it elsewhere.  SVN has a lot of documentation, and Googling for things like "installing SVN" or "creating an SVN repository" should help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure SVN and Apache together. [Documentation is here](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.serverconfig.httpd.html). However, please read [David's comments](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12640305/215966). I have to agree 100%.